# PHP Insert or update table

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli, sql-update

Let me explain what I need and canot get :(
I have to DB one i main the other is just getting part of data from the firs one.

This is my code:

```
foreach($id_product_array AS $id_product) {
$resultf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db1_available_product WHERE id_product='".$id_product."'");
while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($resultf)) {
$aa1=$rowi['id_product'];
$aa2=$rowi['date'];
$aa3=$rowi['available'];
$aa4=$rowi['published'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO aa_bb.db2_available_product (`id_product`, `date`, `available`, `published`) VALUES ('".$aa1."','".$aa2."', '".$aa3."', '".$aa4."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id_product` = '".$aa1."', `date` = '".$aa2."', `available` = '".$aa3."', `published` = '".$aa4."'");
}
```

The problem is that this multiples the record in DB2 so I am now in millions!!!
Its set up as cron job on 1h basis.

What I need is ether it checks what is existing and don't touch it or if need on update or insert.

The other solution would be to delete the whole table in DB2 then to insert a fresh one from DB1

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: please, please, please, switch to using a form of `PDO`, or `mysqli_*` functions

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your query like so:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM tbl1
ON DUPLICATE ...
```

[See the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for MySQL's [proprietary REPLACE command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///replace.html). It has the same syntax as a regular INSERT, but it checks for duplicate primary key before inserting, and if it is found it will do an UPDATE instead:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Of course you will have to define a unique PK/index on your table that allows this functionality to work.

Comment: So do i only "replace" INSERT with REPLACE in the upper cod or? Sorry if this question sounds stupid!

Comment: I didn't link the documentation for nothing. The precise implementation is up to you.

Comment: sorry I am to stupid to figure out this one by my self! Will tray some other solution! But thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

here is an update!

I solved the problem :)

Thanks s to Niels because he made me rethink my strategy so the solution was simple.

In the DB1 and DB2 there is and ID filed
A added
$aa5=$rowi['id'];
so that made ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE work correctly!

```
foreach($id_product_array AS $id_product) {
$resultf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db1_available_product WHERE id_product='".$id_product."'");
while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($resultf)) {
$aa5=$rowi['id'];
$aa1=$rowi['id_product'];
$aa2=$rowi['date'];
$aa3=$rowi['available'];
$aa4=$rowi['published'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO aa_bb.db2_available_product (`id`,`id_product`, `date`, `available`, `published`) VALUES ('".$aa5."','".$aa1."','".$aa2."', '".$aa3."', '".$aa4."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = '".$aa5."',`id_product` = '".$aa1."', `date` = '".$aa2."', `available` = '".$aa3."', `published` = '".$aa4."'");
}
```

and it seams that it is working OK!
:)